# Passing null to a method with a nullable decimal parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts a nullable decimal which signature looks a little like this:

```
public void MyMethod(decimal? param1)
```

What I'm passing is conditional, so I'm either passing a decimal value or null.

```
MyMethod((PassNullIfThisIsTrue) ? null : passThisDecimal);
```

VisualStudio say I can't do this because there's on implicit conversion between null and decimal.  So I cast null as a nullable decimal thusly:

```
MyMethod((PassNullIfThisIsTrue) ? (decimal?)null : passThisDecimal);
```

VisualStudio is happy, but when I pass this cast null, I'm seeing param1 equaling 0.

Could someone explain what's going on here and/or the best way to handle a situation like this?  I should note that I do not want to change the value of passThisDecimal.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try casting `passThisDecimal` as a nullable decimal. Otherwise you're passing either a nullable decimal or a non-nullable decimal.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple no, because one of the operands is something the other can be implicitly widened too, so that's what happens. With both `test ? (decimal?)null : someDecimal` and `test ? null : (decimal?)someDecimal` the type is going to be `decimal?` either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VisualStudio is happy, but when I pass this cast null, I'm seeing param1 equaling 0.

Chances are that `PassNullIfThisIsTrue` is actually false, so you're passing the non-null `passThisDecimal` value, which I'm guessing is zero at this point.

In other words, the code you're working with is correct (even though the code you posted here has a typo that would prevent it from compiling), but you're not providing the appropriate inputs to test the code path you're expecting to hit.

Comment: PassNullIfThisIsTrue was most certainly false (sigh).  Thank you for taking the time to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

`(?decimal)` is wrong syntax it should be `(decimal?)`

Do this

```
MyMethod((PassNullIfThisIsTrue) ? null : (decimal?)passThisDecimal);
```

Or this

```
MyMethod((PassNullIfThisIsTrue) ? (decimal?)null : passThisDecimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
MyMethod(PassNullIfThisIsTrue ? null : new decimal?(passThisDecimal));
```